# Best way to search the the second array in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I have a grid of values, represented by a two-dimensional array.

Here is a literal representation of the data: `dataValues[row][column]`

So `dataValues[3][0]` would be the fourth row, first column.

Well, I need to search the first column of every row for a value and I'm looking for the least computational intensive way of doing that.

I know I can do it with a loop:

```
for (var i in dataValues) {
  if (dataValues[i][0] == "Totals") {
    matchingRow = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

But I like to avoid loops wherever possible and I can't think of a way to apply `Array.prototype.indexOf` in a useful way here.

Is there even a computational difference between a loop and indexOf? It seems to me that indexOf would probably just run its own loop.

Comment: Any other array prototype  methods will use internal loop. No way to avoid looping but at least with a `for()` you can easily break the loop. Methods like `find()` will also break on first truthy instance

Comment: Also depends on what you need in return

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which will break once condition is met and return first matching element or return `undefined` if condition is not met

```
let matchingItem = dataValues.find(arr=> arr[0] == "Totals");
if(matchingItem ){
  // do what you want with matching elemnt of dataValues
}
```